# C# PayPal REST API Checkout with Credit Card

Tags: rest, paypal

Here is my code for checking out with a credit card. Using PayPal Trans works fine but I am missing something for credit card trans.

```
HttpContext CurrContext = HttpContext.Current;    
APIContext apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();    
Item item = new Item();
            item.name = _ItemDescription;
            item.currency = "USD";
            item.price = _Amount;
            item.quantity = "1";
            item.sku = _UPC;

            List<Item> itms = new List<Item>();
            itms.Add(item);
            ItemList itemList = new ItemList();
            itemList.items = itms;

            Address billingAddress = new Address();
            billingAddress.city = ciTxBx.Text;
            billingAddress.country_code = "US";
            billingAddress.line1 = ad1TxBx.Text;
            billingAddress.line2 = ad2TxBx.Text;
            billingAddress.postal_code = pcTxBx.Text;
            billingAddress.state = stRcb.SelectedValue.ToString();

            CreditCard crdtCard = new CreditCard();
            crdtCard.billing_address = billingAddress;
            crdtCard.cvv2 = scTxBx.Text;
            crdtCard.expire_month = Convert.ToInt32(emonthTxBx.Text);
            crdtCard.expire_year = Convert.ToInt32(eyearTxBx.Text);
            crdtCard.first_name = ccfnTxBx.Text;
            crdtCard.last_name = cclnTxBx.Text;
            crdtCard.number = ccnTxBx.Text;
            crdtCard.type = ConvertLower(cctRcb.SelectedValue.ToString());

            Details details = new Details();
            details.tax = "0";
            details.shipping = "0";
            details.subtotal = _Amount;

            Amount amont = new Amount();
            amont.currency = "USD";
            amont.total = _Amount;
            amont.details = details;

            Transaction tran = new Transaction();
            tran.amount = amont;
            tran.description = _ItemDescription;
            tran.item_list = itemList;

            List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
            transactions.Add(tran);

            FundingInstrument fundInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
            fundInstrument.credit_card = crdtCard;

            List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstrumentList = new List<FundingInstrument>();
            fundingInstrumentList.Add(fundInstrument);

            PayerInfo pi = new PayerInfo();
            pi.email = emTxBx.Text;
            pi.first_name = fnTxBx.Text;
            pi.last_name = lnTxBx.Text;
            pi.shipping_address = billingAddress;

            Payer payr = new Payer();
            payr.funding_instruments = fundingInstrumentList;
            payr.payment_method = "credit_card";
            payr.payer_info = pi;

            Payment paymnt = new Payment();
            paymnt.intent = "sale";
            paymnt.payer = payr;
            paymnt.transactions = transactions;
            try
            {
                Payment createdPayment = paymnt.Create(apiContext);
                CurrContext.Items.Add("ResponseJson", JObject.Parse(createdPayment.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Formatting.Indented));
            }
            catch (PayPal.Exception.PayPalException ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException is PayPal.Exception.ConnectionException)
                {
                    CurrContext.Response.Write(((PayPal.Exception.ConnectionException)ex.InnerException).Response);
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrContext.Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            CurrContext.Items.Add("RequestJson", JObject.Parse(paymnt.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Formatting.Indented));
```

Anyone know why I am receiving a "No payload for this request" message?

Comment: Seems you have no [`PayerInfo` for your `Payer`](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#payer-object). Hth...

Comment: I have made edits to my original post. Thanks for posting. Still no joy though.

Comment: So after examining the sandbox I see the credit card transaction listed but still the website showing error "No payload for this request". Any other ideas?

Comment: Can anyone help me. I'm desperate to get this working. Thank you.

Comment: Does the above actually compile?  `pi.shipping_address = billingAddress;` re: `Address` vs. `ShippingAddress` (`PayerInfo`)

Comment: yes it does compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after mocking your code (and hard-coding values), the line that I commented on is the only thing I corrected to make it work (I don't know how/why your code would compile):

```cs
pi.shipping_address = new ShippingAddress
{
   city = "San Mateo",
   country_code = "US",
   line1 = "SO TEST",
   line2 = "",
   postal_code = "94002",
   state = "CA",
 };
```

And finally the (successful) response from PayPal (`ResponseJson`):

```js
ResponseJson: {
    "id": "PAY-8EU11336Y2032051SKUYZZOQ",
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "credit_card",
        "funding_instruments": [{
            "credit_card": {
                "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx2274",
                "type": "visa",
                "expire_month": 1,
                "expire_year": 2018,
                "first_name": "Stack",
                "last_name": "Overflow",
                "billing_address": {
                    "line1": "SO TEST",
                    "line2": "",
                    "city": "San Mateo",
                    "country_code": "US",
                    "postal_code": "94002",
                    "state": "CA"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "related_resources": [{
            "sale": {
                "id": "1Y28050325502832C",
                "amount": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "total": "99.00"
                },
                "state": "completed",
                "parent_payment": "PAY-8EU11336Y2032051SKUYZZOQ",
                "create_time": "2015-04-17T23:52:26Z",
                "update_time": "2015-04-17T23:52:28Z",
                "links": [{
                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/1Y28050325502832C",
                    "rel": "self",
                    "method": "GET"
                },
                {
                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/1Y28050325502832C/refund",
                    "rel": "refund",
                    "method": "POST"
                },
                {
                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8EU11336Y2032051SKUYZZOQ",
                    "rel": "parent_payment",
                    "method": "GET"
                }]
            }
        }],
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "99.00",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": "99.00"
            }
        },
        "description": "trnx desc",
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "quantity": "1",
                "name": "foo",
                "price": "99.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "sku": "fooSku"
            }]
        }
    }],
    "state": "approved",
    "create_time": "2015-04-17T23:52:26Z",
    "update_time": "2015-04-17T23:52:28Z",
    "links": [{
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8EU11336Y2032051SKUYZZOQ",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET"
    }]
}
```

And shown in Paypal developer Sandbox Transactions:

[image: screen shot paypal developer]

Hth...

Comment: Would you mind posting your code so that I may do a comparison to mine. thank you.

Comment: This is so frustrating! I am still receiving the same error that there is no payload. Does anyone have C# code for PayPal using a credit card? I would hate to have to go back to classic PayPal.

Comment: @RooGuru I used your code, except for the variables coming from controls (I just provided hard coded values). The only other thing I changed was the line for `ShippingAddress`. Are you doing the above in an asp.net app context? I am (and that maybe where we differ?). Another assumption is that you are using the .Net SDK (based on the methods and object names you used, still its just my assumption).

Comment: I am using context and I do have the SDK installed. Should I not be using the SDK?

Comment: @RooGuru - use the SDK (I am). Where exactly to you hit that error? As you can tell, I can't seem to repro it....

Comment: I have a Server.Transfer to another page to give results.

Comment: If you could post your code of the complete code behind I could compare the 2 to make sure I'm doing exactly as you are. Please include .dll files you are using and declarations. this would help immensely.

Comment: @RooGuru - I think you should post yours because as above, I didn't do anything different (with the above exceptions - hard coded values, `ShippingAddress`) in fact I copied and pasted your code originally just to mock it. You mention `Server.Transfer` and somewhere above you actually said you could see the transaction in `Paypal` (?) so your error may actually have nothing to do with Paypal....

Comment: Im not sure why you wont post your code? My code is the same as above except added shippingaddress & payer_info. Obviously you have done something else to make it work.

Comment: @RooGuru No problem, [here you go](https://gist.github.com/EdSF/e143a0a272474c21b360)....

Comment: Perfect thank you. I knew if I could do a comparison I would find the discrepancies. I've got it working now thanks to your code posting.